# Symfony3: dynamic subdomains

Tags: php, symfony, routes, subdomain

For the project I'm working on I need using dynamic subdomains for every customer that is using the service. By default the / route should match to the indexAction, but every site following the schema **slug.domain.com** should use the slugIndexAction.

Also, the hostname should be dynamic, too. (Defined in the parameters.yml)

My current setup looks like this:

```
slug_index:
    path:     /
    host:     "{slug}.{domain}"
    defaults:
        _controller: app.controller.frontend:slugIndexAction
        domain: '%domain%'
    requirements:
        domain: '%domain%'

index:
  path: /
  defaults:
      _controller:  app.controller.frontend:indexAction
```

In this case it always matches the index route, even if I use a subdomain. I also tried using hardcoded slugs and hostnames, but that didn't work either.

When the index route is removed, I get a ResourceNotFoundException / NotFoundHttpException

> No route found for "GET /"

```
http://test.localhost:8000/
```

Also, would it be possible to use the same controller in both cases as they're basically doing the same, the slugs are used for modifying the css and headings.

Comment: What about to parse `$request->getHost()` into `indexAction` and get rid of the `slug_index` route?

Comment: @yceruto  this would be an option, I thought using the routing would be better regarding best practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Symfony docs show an example of [routing a sub-domain homepage to a specific action](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html#using-placeholders)

In a yaml configuration, this is:

```
projects_homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     "{project_name}.example.com"
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Main:projectsHomepage }
    # $project_name would be a variable to projectsHomepageAction()

homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Main:homepage }
```

You can also use the same controller action - I've done similar with different routes (but not on a sub-domain) with default variables, that don't appear in the URL, but are set based on the route that was used:

```
 * # for iframe-use - optionally, with partner-friendly footers
 * @Route("/",         name="homepage_menus",          defaults={"hasMenus"=true, "partnerLinks"=false})
 * @Route("/partners", name="homepage_partner_footer", defaults={"hasMenus"=false,"partnerLinks"=true})
 *
 * @Route("/body-only", name="homepage_body_only", defaults={"hasMenus"=false,"partnerLinks"=false})
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request, $hasMenus = false, $partnerLinks = false)
```